# Processmaker 4 create Database

Tags: processmaker

I manager to install and configure Processmaker 4 on windows apache server, how ever I am facing one big problem, hot to create the database schema? is there an sql file i should run?
Or there any empty database I can import to my Database
Any Help

Answer (score 0):

The database is setup in an init step.

I altered the version I found in the docker image and I run something like:

```
php artisan processmaker:install --no-interaction \
--url=${APP_URL} \
--broadcast-host=${PM_BROADCAST_HOST} \
--username=admin \
--password=${PM_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASS} \
--email=admin@processmaker.com \
--first-name=Admin \
--last-name=User \
--db-host=${PM_DB_HOST} \
--db-port=${PM_DB_PORT} \
--db-name=${PM_DB_NAME} \
--db-username=${PM_DB_USERNAME} \
--db-password=${PM_DB_PASSWORD} \
--data-driver=mysql \
--data-host=${PM_DB_HOST} \
--data-port=${PM_DB_PORT} \
--data-name=${PM_DB_NAME} \
--data-username=${PM_DB_USERNAME} \
--data-password=${PM_DB_PASSWORD} \
--redis-host=redis
```

In case it helps I have a little script I created to setup the database:

```
drop database IF EXISTS processmaker;
create database processmaker CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
grant ALL on processmaker.* TO pm@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

exit
```

(Of course that's a test dev machine password)